# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. in git bash

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I faced this problem where it says 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. when i try to execute ***npm start*** from git bash cli.

```
$ npm start

> queensland-weather@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\react\project
> react-scripts start

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-16T01_35_47_855Z-debug.log
```

However, if i execute node -v or npm -v from git bash, it returns me result

```
Derek MINGW64 ~/Desktop/react/project (master)
$ npm -v
5.6.0

Derek MINGW64 ~/Desktop/react/project (master)
$ node -v
v9.5.0
```

And if i execute the same thing from windows cmd, it works:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view project in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000/
On Your Network:  http://192.168.10.1:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

UPDATE:

Added node and npm into environment variable

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'd been searching for the answer to this and all I got was 'add nodejs to the path', which I had already done (and actually is done by node on installation)
Finally discovered that git bash is sensitive to spaces in the PATH variable.

So... the safest way is to add a slash after the path variable so you are sure that there is no space after "\nodejs" part, i.e.

C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Answer (score 2):

If you have added the path correctly, try installing the nodejs installer with all the features enabled.

Comment: hmm, it was working perfectly on cmd and powershell.. why isn't it working on cygwin or git bash?

Comment: Try to create a shortcut from git-bash.exe and add this command: " --no-cd --command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i"

Answer (score 1):

Adding this as confirmation of Peter Koopman's answer, which I have upvoted. I had to do exactly the same for a local automation test project using Newman to test an api. As I use git bash for nearly everything and I wanted to run my program from a double-click shortcut

[image: Win 10 - Env Variable - PATH - nodejs]